# Scala 3 - creating an object without "new" with primary constructor with default values and a secondary constructor

Tags: scala, scala-3

Scala 3.3.1

I have this code:

```
class Person(
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    val birthYear: Int = -1,
    val address: String = ""
) {}

@main
def main() = {
  val p1 = Person("John", "Doe")
  val p2 = Person("Jane", "Doe", 1900)
  val p3 = Person("Josh", "Doe", 1912, "Main Street")
}
```

This works correctly, I can create objects without `new`, using the default values.

Now if I introduce a secondary constructor, it breaks:

```
class Person(
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    val birthYear: Int = -1,
    val address: String = ""
):
  def this() = this("John", "Doe")
```

It detects errors on 2 first lines of main: `None of the overloaded alternatives of method apply in object Person with types (): Person (firstName: String, lastName: String, birthYear: Int, address: String): Person match arguments (("John" : String), ("Doe" : String))` and `None of the overloaded alternatives of method apply in object Person with types (): Person (firstName: String, lastName: String, birthYear: Int, address: String): Person match arguments (("Jane" : String), ("Doe" : String), (1900 : Int))`. The 3rd line works correctly. If I create the objects with `new`, everything works fine.

What's weird is that if I define a secondary constructor with the same number of arguments as a constructor I'm trying to use (but with completely different types), it works. For example:

```
class Person(
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    val birthYear: Int = -1,
    val address: String = ""
):
  def this(x: Int, y: Int) = this("John1", "Doe1")
  def this(x: Array[List[HashMap[Int, String]]], y: Boolean, z: Int) =
    this("John2", "Doe2")

@main
def main() = {
  val p1 = Person("John", "Doe")
  val p2 = Person("Jane", "Doe", 1900)
  val p3 = Person("Josh", "Doe", 1912, "Main Street")
} // no errors
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce and believe this is a bug. I submitted [an issue](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/19201) on the Dotty repository.

The problem appears to stem from the interaction between [universal apply methods](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/other-new-features/creator-applications.html) and [default parameter values](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/default-parameter-values.html). Essentially, the compiler automatically generates `apply` methods that forward to constructors in the companion object of classes. However, these methods do not include default parameters. Hypothesis: when there is a single constructor, the compiler is able to trace back to the original constructor's default parameters, but not when there are multiple constructors.